# Geometric intuition of isolated and embedded prime of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime

> In a commutative ring R, minimal elements in $\text{Ass}(M)$ (with respect to the set-theoretic inclusion) are called **isolated primes** while the rest of the associated primes (i.e., those properly containing associated primes) are called **embedded primes**.

Is there any geometric way of thinking about this "isolated and embedded prime"? To which concept do they relate in algebraic geometry?

Comment: They correspond to irreducible components and embedded components of schemes. This example may be helpful, a subscheme defined by $(x^2,xy)$ in $A^2$.

Comment: Ravi Vakil’s notes on algebraic geometry have a very nice discussion of these, giving a lot of geometric intuition.

Comment: @Joppy How can I find these notes? They are not in Foundations of Algebraic Geometry.